# How can my TFTP server host files larger than 2GB?

Tags: files, 32-bit, pxe, tftp

I have a working TFTP server via the `tftp-hpa` package on my Ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit) installation. It can server OS for PXE booting over the network if the OS size is under 2GB.

When I try to boot from the larger ISO over the network, the booting PXE client reports:

```
loading big.iso failed. no such file or directory
```

The `big.iso` file definitely exists so I attempted to debug  the issue with the tftp server:

```
me@box$ tftp 192.168.1.1
tftp> get pxelinux.cfg/default
sent RRQ <file=pxelinux.cfg/default, mode=netascii>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=2, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=2>
received DATA <block=3, 305 bytes>
Received 1329 bytes in 0.0 seconds
tftp> get big.iso
tftp: big.iso: Value too large for defined data type
tftp>
```

This reminds me of the error I get when interacting with files over 2GB in size with older programs. Is there a way I can get the `tftp-hpa` to serve `big.iso` on my 32 bit system?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355964

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm willing to recompile the `tftp-hpa` package from source with the appropriate flag, but I can't find the source repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source for the HPA tftp/tftpd with `apt source tftpd-hpa`.

Have you tried transferring a file >2G with the hpa tftp client? If that succeeds, the culprit is the PXE boot code, and there is very little you can do about it.

In any case, PXE is not supposed to load the entire filesystem image; it should just load the kernel and initrd, and access the filesystem image with NFS.